# Logical error in pointer assignments in calculating polynomial sum using pointer based linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to write a program to perform addition of two polynomials in C using pointers and linked list. This looks like this:

Live code on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/AYBLHB).

```
1    #include<stdio.h>
2    #include<malloc.h>
3    
4    typedef struct PolyTerm PolyTerm;
5    
6    struct PolyTerm
7    {
8       int coeff;
9       int exp;
10      PolyTerm *next;
11    };
12    
13    void printPoly(PolyTerm *pPoly)
14    {
15      if(pPoly == NULL)
16      {
17          printf("\n");
18          return;
19      }
20      printf("%de%d",pPoly->coeff,pPoly->exp);
21      if(pPoly->next != NULL)
22          printf(" + ");
23      printPoly(pPoly->next);
24    }
25    
26    void printPolyTerm(PolyTerm *pPoly)
27    {
28      if(pPoly != NULL)
29          printf("%de%d",pPoly->coeff,pPoly->exp);
30    }
31    
32    void createPolyTerm(int pCoeff, int pExp, PolyTerm **pPoly)
33    {
34      PolyTerm *tempPolyTerm;
35      if(*pPoly == NULL)
36      {
37          tempPolyTerm = (PolyTerm *)malloc(sizeof(PolyTerm));
38          tempPolyTerm -> coeff = pCoeff;
39          tempPolyTerm -> exp = pExp;
40          
41          *pPoly = tempPolyTerm;
42      }
43      else
44      {
45          (*pPoly)->coeff = pCoeff;   
46          (*pPoly)->exp = pExp;
47          (*pPoly)->next = (PolyTerm *)malloc(sizeof(PolyTerm));
48          (*pPoly)->next->next = NULL;
49      }
50    }
51    
52    void addPoly(PolyTerm **pFirstPoly,PolyTerm **pSecondPoly, PolyTerm **sumPoly)
53    {
54      PolyTerm *sumPolyIterator = *sumPoly;
55      PolyTerm *sumPolyIteratorParent = *sumPoly;
56      PolyTerm *firstPolyCurrentTerm = *pFirstPoly;
57      PolyTerm *secondPolyIterator = *pSecondPoly;
58      
59      while(firstPolyCurrentTerm != NULL)
60      {
61          //find if current exp exist in sumPoly
62          while(sumPolyIterator != NULL)
63          {
64              printf("-Sum: ");       
65              printPoly(*sumPoly);   //in last iteration, prints 6e0 + 9e1
66              printf("inner while 1\n");
67              printf("sumPolyIterator:%de%d\n",sumPolyIterator->coeff,sumPolyIterator->exp);
68              *sumPolyIteratorParent = *sumPolyIterator;
69              if(sumPolyIterator->exp == firstPolyCurrentTerm->exp)
70                  break;
71              sumPolyIterator = sumPolyIterator->next;
72              printf("-Sum: ");
73              printPoly(*sumPoly);   //in last iteration, prints 9e1, where did 6e0 went?
74          }
75          
76          if(sumPolyIterator == NULL)
77          {
78              //if the exp is not present in sum yet, create it
79              sumPolyIterator = (PolyTerm *)malloc(sizeof(PolyTerm)); 
80              sumPolyIteratorParent->next = sumPolyIterator;
81          }
82          
83          sumPolyIterator->exp += firstPolyCurrentTerm->exp;
84          sumPolyIterator->coeff = firstPolyCurrentTerm->coeff;
85          
86          //iterate through second polynomial to find all terms with same exp
87          while(secondPolyIterator != NULL)
88          {
89              if(secondPolyIterator->exp == firstPolyCurrentTerm->exp)
90              {
91                  sumPolyIterator->coeff += secondPolyIterator->coeff;
92              }
93              secondPolyIterator = secondPolyIterator->next;
94          }
95          
96          //reset to first term
97          sumPolyIterator = *sumPoly;
98          secondPolyIterator = *pSecondPoly;
99          
100         firstPolyCurrentTerm = firstPolyCurrentTerm->next;
101     }
102    }
103    
104    void main()
105    {
106     PolyTerm *firstPolyTerm = NULL;   
107     createPolyTerm(1,0,&firstPolyTerm);
108     createPolyTerm(2,1,&(firstPolyTerm->next));           
109     createPolyTerm(3,2,&(firstPolyTerm->next->next));
110     
111     PolyTerm *secondPolyTerm = NULL;
112     createPolyTerm(5,0,&secondPolyTerm);
113     createPolyTerm(7,1,&(secondPolyTerm->next));           
114     createPolyTerm(9,2,&(secondPolyTerm->next->next));
115     
116     PolyTerm *sumPolyFirstTerm = (PolyTerm *)malloc(sizeof(PolyTerm));
117     PolyTerm **sumPoly = &sumPolyFirstTerm;
118     addPoly(&firstPolyTerm,&secondPolyTerm,&sumPolyFirstTerm);
119     
120     printPoly(firstPolyTerm);
121     printPoly(secondPolyTerm);
122     printPoly(sumPolyFirstTerm);
123    }
```

The output is:

```
-Sum: 0e0
inner while 1
sumPolyIterator:0e0
-Sum: 6e0
inner while 1
sumPolyIterator:6e0
-Sum: 6e0
-Sum: 6e0 + 9e1
inner while 1
sumPolyIterator:6e0
-Sum: 6e0 + 9e1
-Sum: 6e0 + 9e1
inner while 1
sumPolyIterator:9e1
-Sum: 9e1
1e0 + 2e1 + 3e2
5e0 + 7e1 + 9e2
9e1 + 12e2
```

The sum of two polynomials, `1e0 + 2e1 + 3e2` and `5e0 + 7e1 + 9e2` is `6e0+9e1+12e2`. However, on the last line it prints `9e1 + 12e2`. Seems that first term `6e0` is lost in some pointer assignments. So I tried putting `printf` statements with prefix `-Sum`. As you can see in the output, the last line prefixed with `-Sum` is `-Sum: 9e1`, whereas the second last line prefixed with `-Sum` is `-Sum: 6e0 + 9e1`. So thats seems where the first term `6e0` is lost. I have commented the code pointing out where these `-Sum` prefixed lines are printed (its first inner while loop in `addPoly()` method, line 65 and 73), but I am unable to understand why this is happening.

Comment: `malloc.h` is not a standard header. `malloc` & co are declared in `stdlib.h`. And use a debugger to provide a more precise description of the problem.

Comment: I tried debugging, but eclipse is failing badly, it behaves improperly, misses breakpoints. So, I have put `printf`s (printing lines prefixed with `-Sum`) and tried to narrow down the issue to the first inner while loop, but I am not able to clearly demarcate whats wrong. Please read the explanation at the end of the question.

Comment: @Olaf added line numbers, comments are on line 65 and 73. Also you can find the running code on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/AYBLHB).

Comment: I would rethink what `createPolyTerm` should do. At the moment it is very hard to use correctly, as it (sometimes!) creates an uninitialized term at the end of the list.

Comment: Adding line-numbers is a very bad idea - where did I criticised missing line-numbers? That way the code can not be copy/pasted to an editor/run-time. Just don't. Missing breakpoints is most likely not a problem of Eclipse (actually the debugger, Eclipse is an IDE), but having optimisations enabled on the compiler. If you use gcc, use `-Og` (recommended) or `-O0` for the debug version of your code.

Comment: @alain By unintialized, do you mean the `next` pointer of the last element is `NULL`? Yes it is. Isnt it natural as it indicates their are no more terms in the polynomial. Also its working correctly I guess, as `printPoly()` calls on lines 120 and 121 correctly prints the two polynomials `firstPolyTerm` and `secondPolyTerm`. The issues is seems to be precisely in first inner while loop between lines 65 and 73, as can be seen from the output. Thats where the first term `6e0` vanishes.

Comment: @Olaf I know it is indeed a bad idea to put line numbers, but it helps in discussions. Also for the same purpose I put the code on ideone.com, so that one can copy from their or fork or run. Honestly I long felt stackoverflow should provide auto line numbers toggle by default. About those arguments, I have to try...

Comment: No I meant `coeff` and `exp` are uninitialized. IMHO the function should always allocate a new `PolyTerm` and set `coeff` and `exp` on the newly created item, rather than set it on the previous item and create an uninitialized new one.

Comment: @alain Ok anyways...I used `NULL` endterm notion to demarket polynomial end. I was having doubt in `addPoly()`. Anything about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your program doesn't work out of the box due to usage of uninitialized data. It happens to work on ideone by chance, but in general case it must fail like it did on my system. Example: in `createPolyTerm` you creates `tempPolyTerm`, where field `next` isn't initialized at all, so it contains garbage. However, you continue as if `next` was set to `NULL`. Another example: `sumPolyFirstTerm` is created by allocating buffer with `malloc`, no member is initialized. However, within `addPoly` you pass it into `printPoly` expecting `NULL` in `next` field.

If you rely on buffer data to be always set to zero on allocation, use [calloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/) instead of `malloc`, at least that was the way to make your program running on my system.

Ok, back to your trouble. It looks like the following string contains error

```
*sumPolyIteratorParent = *sumPolyIterator;
```

You probably wanted to point parent iterator to current position of base iterator, but instead you used dereferencing and updated PolyTerm itself instead of changing iterators. With this replacement program looks working OK:

```
sumPolyIteratorParent = sumPolyIterator;
```